# Erro no export de Entidades - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, eclipse

Boa tarde pessoal!

Estou tentando criar as tabelas do banco a partir das entidades que criei no projeto.
Quando peço para criar as tabelas e exibir o script de criação do banco pelo Eclipse tenho esse erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:98)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:52)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.buildEntityManagerFactory(Main.java:94)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.execute(Main.java:80)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.main(Main.java:68)
```

Não sei onde pode ser o problema.
Procurei na net e parece que pode ser a falta de uma lib do Jboss, mas estou usando ApacheTomCat.

Alguém tem alguma ideia porque desse erro?

Segue meu pom.xml do Maven

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>br.com.bse</groupId>
<artifactId>manager</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>manager Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Google Gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.spring.framework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.spring.framework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.spring.framework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.spring.framework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate Aspect -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JBoss -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>manager</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <!-- Compiler -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Pelo que dá pra ver na exceção, é falta do pacote `jboss-logging`: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging

Comment: A lib do jboss que está faltando neste caso é a do Logger. Por isso o erro.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas. Como podem ver eu já importei essa lib de loggin com o Maven, mas o erro persiste. Vejam o pom.xml que postei acima na pergunta. Será que esta correto o import?

Comment: Você está usando Spring Boot nesse projeto? Veja a resposta [dessa pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547015/hibernate-5-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-jboss-logging-logger-debugf)

Comment: Estou usando spring normal mesmo. Não é o springboot não.

Comment: Alguma sugestão pessoal?